# How to install azCopy on linux in vsts online build task?

Tags: linux, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azcopy

My goal is, on hosted linux preview, copy built/archived zip file to azure storage file system.

On Hosted linux preview , I would like to copy build archive (single zip file) from VSTS build to azure storage file using azCopy. I've tried both flavors of instructions for [install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-linux?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ffiles%2Ftoc.json) for linux. Both fail with

```
2018-05-06T23:59:51.7967023Z 2018-05-06 23:59:50 (53.5 MB/s) - ‘azcopy.tar.gz’ saved [68428738/68428738]
2018-05-06T23:59:51.7975469Z 
2018-05-06T23:59:52.8481973Z ./install.sh: line 20: rsync: command not found
```

Everything before and after this error is correct. How do I install azCopy into Hosted linux preview.

The build task runs a [script](https://github.com/v-geberr/ng-cli-5-hello-world/blob/master/azCopy.sh). The variables in the script echo correctly.

**EDITS :**

When I try to use the command line to use azCopy directly, I get

```
******************************************************************************
Starting: Run azCopy
******************************************************************************
==============================================================================
Task         : Command Line
Description  : Run a command line with arguments
Version      : 1.1.3
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613735)
==============================================================================
Failed which: Not found azCopy: null
undefined failed with error: Failed which: Not found azCopy: null
******************************************************************************
Finishing: Run azCopy
******************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The azCopy is available on Hosted linux preview agent, so call azcopy command directly (e.g. Command line, azure cli tasks)

Comment: Added "Edit" section with results - it doesn't work -- so far anyway.

Comment: @DFBerry Using `azcopy` instead (lowercase).